# Ngx-mask Enforcing Validation on Input fields in production

Tags: javascript, angular7, input-mask

My Input looks like this: I just want to use input mask but not enforce the user to strictly fill the pattern in the mask.

```
<input type="text" class="Enter Zipcode" placeholder="Enter Zipcode" mask="00000-0000" formControlName="zipcode">
```

Seems like according to [documentation](https://github.com/JsDaddy/ngx-mask#usage-13) [validation]=true by default. But should be some way to change validation to false. When I do it

```
<input type="text" class="Enter Zipcode" placeholder="Enter Zipcode" mask="00000-0000" formControlName="zipcode" [validation]="true">

ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'validation' since it isn't a known property of 'input'. ("text" class="Enter Zipcode" placeholder="Enter Zipcode" mask="00000-0000" formControlName="zipcode" [ERROR ->][validation]="false">
```

Angular throws template parse errors ?

Answer (score 5):

Use `mask="99999-9999"`. According to ngx-mask documentation the 0's are used for required numeric fields and the 9's for optional numeric fields.